# Where does one apply for 6 month Indian tourist visa?

Tags: india, thailand, tourist-visas, lithuanian-citizens

Everywhere I looked [I only could find e-Visas](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/tvoa.html) that are 1 month long...

I managed to find this [website which shows that visa](http://www.vfsglobal.com/india/uk/Tourist.html) is 35£ (+ their fee) so there should be a way to apply for it...

**Where can one apply for 6 month Indian tourist (or some other) visa?** (if he is Lithuanian who is in Thailand)

Comment: From what I've found, so far, non-Thai nationals and foreigners who are not Thai permanent residents can only get the 3-month, single entry tourist visas. You can do it in [Cambodia](http://www.indembassyphnompenh.org/) or [Indonesia](http://www.cgibali.in/eoi.php?id=V-Tourist). The Indian Consulate in Vilnius visainfo@blsindiavisa.com might be able to provide additional info.

Comment: tweet to @MEAIndia (Ministry of External Affairs). They would love to help you. 

https://blog.twitter.com/2016/meaindia-takes-citizen-engagement-global-with-twitter-seva

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 2016, the [Embassy of India](http://www.indianembassy.in.th/) in Bangkok and the Chaing Mai Consulate no longer accept applications from non-Thai nationals or permanent residents. Foreigners who are in Thailand on tourist visas can only [apply online for a visa](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/index.html), which is limited to a 30-day visit.

As India does not give in-country extensions of tourist visas, alternatives would be making application from other countries, such as [Cambodia](http://www.indembassyphnompenh.org/pages.php?id=92), [Myanmar](http://www.indiaembassyyangon.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=86&Itemid=235&lang=ENG), [Viet Nam](http://www.india-consulate.org.vn/en/consular-and-visa-services/visa-information), or [Indonesia](http://www.cgibali.in/eoi.php?id=V-Tourist).